# Some key mappings for combinations with the PageUp/PageDown keys don't work

Tags: vim, urxvt

I use `rxvt-unicode` terminal emulator on Manjaro, and the following two mappings in my `.vimrc` don't work,

```
nnoremap <C-PageUp>   :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-PageDown> :tabnext<CR>
```

even though the following does work

```
nnoremap <C-t>        :tabnew<CR>
```

Comment: You know that you have `gt` and `gT` already, right? Anyway, what happens when you try using the first two mappings?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis hello, yes sure. But is doesn't work in insert-mode

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis nothing, nothing happens. I change <C-PageUp> to <C-Up> and everything works with UpArrow

Comment: Maybe it's related to [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/shiftf8-changes-letter-case-for-2-letters-how-to-unmap-this), but I have no clue at the moment. I can try giving a look in the evening, because those mappings don't work for me either.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis ty! I will watch your link right now

Comment: Besides, I suggest that you `set showcmd` in your `.vimrc` file and see what's shown on the last line on screen when you press those mappings; this will help you test the answer I linked (enter `:help showcmd` to know more about this option).

Comment: Furthermore, if you enter `:help i_CTRL-<PageUp>`, you see that actually those mappings should work out of the box.

Comment: Give a look at [Why do <C-PageUp> and <C-PageDown> not work in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814373/why-do-c-pageup-and-c-pagedown-not-work-in-vim). Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for the behavior you observe is exactly the one described [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17250/6498).

In other words, something like this (what the rhs is doesn't matter)

```
nnoremap <C-PageUp> :echo "hello"<CR>
```

will not work as Vim does not now which escape sequence corresponds to the keycode `<C-PageUp>`.

Therefore, you can provide it with the escape sequence corresponding to <kbd>Ctrl-PageUp</kbd>, as in

```
nnoremap ^[[5^ :echo "hello"<CR>
```

where the first two characters of the escape sequence, `^[`, are part of a single unit that corresponds to <kbd>Escape</kbd> (that's why *escape* seqeunce).

You can get the whole sequence (which could be different from mine in your terminal, by the way) from insert mode by hitting
<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+PageUp</kbd>; however, given the meaning of `^[`, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> and then type <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> manually.

Unfortunately, putting `set <C-PageUp>=^[[5^` causes error `E518`. I don't know why.

On the other hand, another solution is the following (again described [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17250/6498))

```
set <F37>=^[[5^
nnoremap <F37> :echo "ciao"<CR>
```

where `<F37>` is one of the extra function keycode Vim provides. I have no clue where this thing is in the `:help`.